# Unable to figureout on my own "[ UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation ]"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot and spring security and not able to understand the following error on my own.
my spring boot application simply contains two URLs one which is accessed by anyone i.e, only by whose name password is saved in database and another which can only ADMIN can access(to add user and there roll in MySql database).
But when i am passing username and password it saying:-

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation
```

**I am posting all necessary class below:-**

**CustomUserDetailService:-**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user= repository.findByname(name);
        CustomUserDetail userDetail=null;
        if(user!=null){
            CustomUserDetail userDetails=new CustomUserDetail();
            userDetails.setUser(user);
        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not exist with name :" +name);
        }
            return null;
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetail**

```
public class CustomUserDetail implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    /*Getter and Setter*/

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /*Overriden methods from userDetail*/

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Role_"+role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**BasicConfig:-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class BasicConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encodePWD());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers("/user/").permitAll()
                     .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers("/MiniApi/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**Controller Classes:-**
*I am not making two @Restcontroller classes and only single @RequestMapping() is acting as base URL*

**AdminController:-**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/MiniApi")
public class Admincontroller
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/admin/add")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        String pwd = user.getPassword();
        String encryptPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);
        user.setPassword(encryptPwd);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "User added successfully...";
    }
}
```

**AnyOne:-**

```
public class AnyOne {

    @GetMapping("/anyone")
    public String Anyone()
    {
        return "processing......";
    }
}
```

**Change what i made:-**
If i am removing return statement from CustomUserDetailService i am getting *return statement missing* error and then i added *return userDetails;*
it gives me :-

First it askes me for username and password i provided it and then this

HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are returning null instead of `userDetails`

```
    @Service
    public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

      @Autowired
      private UserRepository repository;

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws 
                UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user= repository.findByname(name);
        CustomUserDetail userDetail=null;
        if(user != null){
            CustomUserDetail userDetails=new CustomUserDetail();
            userDetails.setUser(user);
            return userDetails;
        } 
        throw new 
            UsernameNotFoundException("User not exist with name :" +name);

            
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to say but i tried it if i am removing retrun null it saying return statement is missing.

Comment: I have updated the post in last section i have mentioned what changes i have made...

Comment: i have mentioned the changes i have made.....and also the output what i get...